# WORLD STATE in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

is WORLD STATE actual chain of blocks (Blockchain) in hyperledger fabric. How it is different from state database?

Answer (score 3):

The world state **is** the state database

Answer (score 1):

Yes, has yacovm said. To clear the ideas I think that this image it's perfect:
[image: Ledger Description]

The full article, from I took the picture, is [this one](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/ledger/ledger.html)